# SQL or OLAP schema design for funnel analysis

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, data-warehouse, olap, powerpivot

I have an ecommerce system where users go through a few stages before they make a purchase (visit website, browse catalog, pick a product, goto purchase page, insert credit details etc...).

Each event is saved in the following SQL events table:

```
SessionId
EventTypeId (PageView, Click, Type),
EventValue (HomePage, Button-1 etc...)
Timestamp
```

Each session is saved in the following Sessions table (simplified):

```
SessionId
SelectedProductId
SessionPurchaseAmount (0 for sessions without a purchase)
```

My question is how to design the Database schema schema so I could use it to filter / analyze sessions by funnel? One more thing I need to figure out is how to flatten the SQL schema to OLAP structure.

The funnel should be defined dynamicaly like they do it in MixPanel / GA / other web analytics platforms.

I want to use PowerPivot to analyze it.

**Example of data:**

Events:

```
SessionId EventType EventValue Timestamp

1         PageView  Home       01:01:00
1         PageView  Catalog    01:02:00
1         PageView  Cart       01:02:30
2         PageView  Home       04:01:03
```

Sessions:

```
SessionId SelectedProduct PurchaseAmount

1         Dress-AA2       $12.00           
2         NULL            $0.00
```

I want to see the result data in a funnel which i define dynamically.
For instance, if I set the funnel to be `Home -> Catalog -> Cart` the data I want to see is:

```
Home     100%
Catalog  50%
Cart     50%
```

Thanks!

Comment: Uri, any example of data?

Comment: Can you just create calculations that are Distinct count of session ids for each event value/total count of distinct session ids? Then you can place them in the order you prefer?

Comment: @mmarie each row in the funnel is a Distinct count of all session that got until that stage AND passed through all previous stages. I can do it with a dynamic SQL but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: @UriAbramson I'm suggesting a better way with Power Pivot.  Create calculated members for each step.

Comment: @mmarie can you please expend a little more about the solution you're offering?