# How can one calculate funnel analysis from a SQL table of raw events?

Tags: sql, data-analysis

How can one calculate funnel analysis from a SQL table of raw events?

For instance, if the funnel is event1 -> event2 -> event3, and this is the data:

```
user1, event1, time1
user1, event2, time2
user1, eventOther, time3
user2, event2, time4
user2, event1, time5
user3, event1, time6
user3, event2, time7
user4, event1, time8
user5, event1, time9
user6, event3, time10
user1, event3, time11
user1, event1, time12
user1, event3, time13
```

Then the funnel would be:

```
event1: 5 (users 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
event2: 2 (users 1 and 3)
event3: 1 (user 1 only)
```

It's similar to this question: [SQL or OLAP schema design for funnel analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367064/sql-or-olap-schema-design-for-funnel-analysis)

It's something like:

```
Query 1: select distinct user ids where event1
Query 2: select distinct user ids where event1 AND THEN event2 (is there an "AND THEN"?)
Query 3: select distinct user ids where event1 AND THEN event2 AND THEN event3
```

Comment: Is this *Funnel Analysis* not simply a *Finite State Automata*?

Answer (score 8):

The generic method would be to use `left join` and aggregation:

```
select count(distinct d1.user) as NumEvent1,
       count(distinct d2.user) as NumEvent2,
       count(distinct d3.user) as NumEvent3
from data d1 left join
     data d2
     on d2.user = d1.user and d2.time > d1.time and d2.event = 'event2' left join
     data d3
     on d3.user = d2.user and d3.time > d2.time and d3.event = 'event3'
where d1.event = 'event1' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the group by:

```
SELECT event, count(*) as 'Responses'
FROM table
GROUP by event;
```

This would give you something like:

| Event | Responses |
| --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 5 |
| Event 2 | 2 |
| Event 3 | 1 |